# Apache Benchmark Document Length vs YSlow Page's Total Weight

Tags: php, yslow, apachebench, page-size

I'm load testing my page with Apache Benchmark:

```
ab -n 20 -c 5 http://localhost/mysite/index/index
```

[image]

I know that **Document Length** stands for the sum of all HTML images,CSS,JS and anything within the response in bytes.

If I go over Firefox and I run YSlow I see that:

```
The page has a total of 22 HTTP requests and a TOTAL WEIGHT of 202.7K bytes 
with empty cache
```

- what's the difference between the document length size and the YSlow page's total weight?

I'd love to know where these definitions (AB/YSlow) differ so that (maybe) I can understand why my AB document length is so high (up to 14000 bytes) compared to other websites (with similar contents, e.g. grubwithus.com) that have a document length not exceeding 91 bytes! However, I also noticed that the YSlow size of my webpage is a way less than the compared size of grubwithus.com (202k against 1124k).

Comment: These are two different tools. Why do you expect that they return the same size?

Answer (score 0):

YSlow counts all linked resources as well (all linked files, from styles, scripts, images up to these crappy flashes and probably even PDFs if they are embedded). ab just pulls the HTML document (at least for the version I know of, which seems to be outdated).

Next to that I think ab gives you the uncompressed sizes but yslow the compressed ones. But I'm no so into yslow to be sure on this. Check their docs for specifics.

Generally both tools do something different. So don't compare their size infos. Ab is for generating load on the server, YSlow is to analyze the nature of the isolated response in context of a webbrowser.

Comment: My manual says that also Ab is returning (Document Lenght) the sum of all HTML images,CSS,JS and anything within the response..

Comment: Okay, this might depend on the ab version used and my knowledge is a bit outdated. However I can imagine that what is considered as linked content differs between both tools and additionally the calculation. For example YSLOW might work with what Firefox actually loads triggered by the request, whereas ab might not resolve links in linked files like conditional javascript loads, automatical triggered javascript requests (ajax and so) as well as css loaded by css rules.

Comment: Luca, you can find out by reading the source code of ab and of firefox and yslow. But I don't think it's worth the trouble. I can only make assumptions like the link-reveal algorithm, compressed/uncompressed values, full HTTP responses incl. HTTP message headers and such. There are multiple points in implementation where this can differ. However, if you want to compare, always use the same tool for (relative) comparisons. Don't compare AB status info with YSLOW status info. If you so dare to know why, read the full sourcecode in question.